# Is ActiveAdmin user logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm looking for a way to check whether a user is logged into activeadmin from within a model. Access to a particular attribute should be denied unless the user is logged in. I was hoping for something like this, but can't find a way to make it work:

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base

  def should_show?

    # find activeadmin user
    if ActiveAdmin.current_admin_user?

      # activeadmin user is logged in
      true

    else

      # not logged in
      false

    end 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Active admin uses [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication.

Use devise's method user_signed_in? for checking signed in user.
Since in active_admin user is called admin_user by default; check it with the following method

`admin_user_signed_in?`

That is in your code replace `ActiveAdmin.current_admin_user?` with `admin_user_signed_in?`